# NOT NULL constraint failed: api_student.author_id

Tags: django, django-admin

I have 10 admin users, and each of them posts 20 posts. There will be 200+ posts in the Student API. I want to show admin only his own 20 posts.
When I want to add a student I got IntegrityError.

Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: api_student.author_id

> Terminal ::: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: api_student.author_id

Models.py

```
    Code = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique = True)
    fullName = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = False)
    banglaName = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='facultyImages/', blank = True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, editable=False)
    email= models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = True)
```

Admin.py

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

     def get_queryset(self, request):
         qs = super(FacultyAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
         return qs.filter(author=request.user)

 admin.site.register(Student, StudentAdmin)
```

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: yes. and my project is running.
Add student >> Save >> exception window

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.

remove `default=None, null=True, editable=False` from models.py and migration> 0001_initial.py

then I migrate my models again.
using commands: `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what Student data was passed, I would suggest in author field add blank=True since you are setting null=True already.

Comment: it's working for the exception solve. but when I saved Nothing show without a successful message. 
Showing: Student with ID “1” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?

Comment: We might need more info to answer this. Since the mail thread was for NOT NULL constraint, I would suggest you to create a new query/thread with additional information like api call, response data, models, serializers etc.